# I can't get abs to work in Pine Script v5

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to find the full size of a candle, bullish or bearish, so I try:
`FullLength = maths.abs(high-low)` and `FullLength = abs(high-low)`
but neither works.
I get the message:

```
Could not find function or function reference 'maths.abs'.
Could not find function or function reference 'abs'.
```

Any ideas much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `v5`, it is `math.abs()` not `maths`.

In `v4`, it is `abs()`.

Comment: Ah yes, that's a d'uh moment! Thank you very much.